# border-bottom поднимает объект

Tags: html, css

Есть меню, сделанное списком `ul > li > a`. Нужно, чтобы при наведении на пункт меню, было подчеркивание. Проблема в том, что `border-bottom` поднимает пункт меню относительно неактивных. `min-height` юзать не очень хочется. Как быть в такой ситуации?

```css
.top_nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top_nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.top_nav ul li a {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  color: #999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.top_nav ul li a.active,
.top_nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  color: #0088CC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0088CC;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Добавить организацию</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="active" href="">Размещение рекламы</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Вот так симпатичнее и эффект такой же**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
li,
a {
  display: table-cell;
}
a {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transition: .3s;
}
a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Ссылка 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Ссылка 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Ссылка 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Ссылка 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/qNZaad?editors=1000

Answer (score 2):

Для этого задайте `border-bottom` изначально, и меняйте цвет с прозрачного (`transparent`) на нужный вам.

```css
.top_nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top_nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.top_nav ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  color: #999;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.top_nav ul li a.active,
.top_nav ul li a:hover {
  border-color: #0088CC;
  color: #0088CC;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Добавить организацию</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="active" href="">Размещение рекламы</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Точно.